# SQL utilizar variável no nome da coluna

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Preciso utilizar variáveis para definir o nome da coluna na minha query sql.

Do genero:

```
SELECT        IDLayout, Nome, @collum, TipoProduto
FROM            ProdutoLayout
WHERE        (TipoProduto = @tipo) AND (@collum = 1)
```

Sendo que a `@collum` é a variável onde se encontra o nome da coluna.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir alterar o nome da coluna pelo `SqlCommand`, pois os parâmetros só servem para adicionar valores.

Terá de fazer isso antes de criar o comando, alterando o SQL original:

```
var valorTipo = "valor do tipo";
var nomeDaColuna = "NomeColuna";
var sql = string.Format(@"
   SELECT     IDLayout, Nome, {0}, TipoProduto
   FROM       ProdutoLayout
   WHERE      (TipoProduto = @tipo) AND ({0} = 1) 
", nomeDaColuna);

var command = new SqlCommand(sql);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", valorTipo);
```

Espero que o nome dessa coluna venha de uma fonte confiável, pois este será um ponto de SQLInjection e que terá de ser tratado se for o caso.

Answer (score 3):

Via SQL mesmo, tem que utilizar o EXEC:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'SELECT        IDLayout, Nome, '+@collum+', TipoProduto
FROM            ProdutoLayout with(nolock)
WHERE        (TipoProduto = '+@tipo+') AND ('+@collum+' = 1) '
exec(@sql)
```

Em se tratando de variaveis em tempo de execução, somente deste modo.

[]´s

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar parametros com o mesmo nome das variáveis da sua query.
Exemplo:

```
var connect = new SqlCommand("String de conexao");
            var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT IDLayout, Nome, @collum, TipoProdutoFROM ProdutoLayout WHERE (TipoProduto = @tipo) AND (@collum = 1) ");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collum", "valor");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", "valor");
```

Comment: A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement.
Obtenho este erro dessa forma.